# Probability for random letters

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

We have to answer the following question for an exercise:

„You have an infinite supply of letters from A-Z. With every draw you pick a random letter (p=1/26) from the supply. How many draws do you need to be 90% certain that you have every letter at least once?
Show the calculations.“

I know that the probability for the first draw to be a new letter is 26/26 and so on (27-n)/26 for the n-th letter. I‘m not sure how I‘m supposed to add all those probabilities together for the „final“ probability to reach 90%. Can anyone give me a hint for it?

Comment: This is a variant of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"90% certain that you have every letter at least once?"* If I have drawn $25$ different letters, P(have drawn all $26$ letters) is still $0$, isn't it ?

Comment: @trueblueanil the number of draws necessary will be around $141$.  The *average* or expected number of draws necessary to find all $n$ coupons at least once each will be $n\cdot H_n$ which here would be around $100$ where here the number of coupons $n$ would be the $26$ letters.  The exact calculation will be messy, probably best left to mathematica using Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind, asking for the first value of $m$ such that $\dfrac{{m\brace {26}}\cdot 26!}{26^m}\geq 0.9$

Comment: See [calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BStirlingS2%5Bm%2C+26%5D+*+26%21%2F26%5Em+%3E+0.9%2C+%7Bm%2C+130%2C150%7D%5D)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the help.